# Can I set pytest command line arguments in conftest?

Tags: python, pytest

The pytest I would like to do will always involve short traceback (`--tb=short`) and report skip reason (`-rsx`)

So instead of needing to do pytest --tb=short -rsx everytime, can I specify it somewhere, maybe conftest.py?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

If you always want to involve short traceback and report skip reason you can write it into a configuration file `pytest.ini`

```
[pytest]
addopts = -rsx --tb=short
```

Alternatively, you can set a `PYTEST_ADDOPTS` environment variable to add command line options while the environment is in use:

```sh
export PYTEST_ADDOPTS="-rsx --tb=short"
```

Comment: Thank you.. pytest.ini will serve well.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Konstantin's answer.

Programmatically set command line arguments, and all other configuration values, inside (ideally) `pytest.ini` inside your tests (or root) folder, or a `pyproject.toml`.

Or an alternative as per https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/customize.html

The reason, which the documentation omits, is that Pytest supports plugins.

Plugins are initialized before conftest.py is evaluated and read the configurations once.

Hence, most configuration options shouldn't be manipulated within conftest.py.